# Why is 'without' sometimes followed by the -ing form of a verb?

Tags: conjunctions

Gentlemen,

I have a problem with the preposition 'without'. Why does it modify verbs into the continuous tense?

Here are a couple of examples:

> I can stand on one foot without *falling*. Why not without fall? Why does it modify the verb into 'ing?
>
> I can watch a movie without *crying*.

Comment: I did clarify my statement, but when I posted it the system deleted most of the post. By the way, it was my first time here, too.

Answer (score 2):

Although the noun phrase is the prototypical object of the preposition (any preposition), it is not the only possibility. See this article at [Answers.com: What follows a preposition?](http://www.answers.com/Q/What_follows_a_preposition).

Quite a few prepositions can take what some call a *'gerund clause' in place of the prototypical noun phrase:

> He left before the end. / He left before looking at his watch.
>
> John thanked Jill for the food. / John thanked Jill for supplying the food.
>
> I can stand on one leg without a crutch. / I can stand on one leg
>   without falling.

Often, where there is a near paraphrase (as in the second example here), the emphasis is switched from the referent of the noun phrase to the action etc of the verb (see below).

See this article at [Grammar-Quizzes.com](http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/gerund3c.html).

*I'd say there is more verbiness than nouniness in the words ending in -ing in these constructions. 'Gerund' has conflicting definitions anyway; I prefer the general term *ing*-form for these whotsits somewhere along the noun-verb continuum.

Comment: Your comment makes sense. Many thanks for answering to my question. Thank you.